# How to add href to custom attribute in customer grid?

Tags: custom-attributes, magento-2.0.7, link, customer-grid

I have created the custom attribute to upload the business proof file during registration. I am able to store the file in `/pub/media` and file name in Database and the file name also displaying in **customer grid**.

How to access the file from admin? Shall we create the href to that column in customer grid to access the file. I have added the screen shot below for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try following way:

1. Add column into your grid list

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/route_model_listing.xml

```
<column name="reference" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Reference">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/columns/reference</item>
            <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Reference</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

2. Create a column class

> Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/Reference.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;

class Reference extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column
{
    const NAME = 'reference';

    const ALT_FIELD = 'name';

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            $fieldName = $this->getData('name');
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $label = $item[$fieldName];
                $item[$fieldName.'_Url'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                    'your/custom/url'
                );
                $item[$fieldName.'_Label'] = $label;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

3. Create component

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/columns/reference.js

```js
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column',
    'jquery',
    'mage/template'
], function (Column, $, mageTemplate) {
    'use strict';

    return Column.extend({
        defaults: {
            bodyTmpl: 'Vendor_Module/grid/cells/reference',
            fieldClass: {
                'data-grid-actions-cell': true
            },
        },
        getLabel: function (record) {
            return record[this.index+'_Label'];
        },
        getUrl: function (record) {
            return record[this.index+'_Url'];
        }
    });
});
```

4. Create template

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/grid/cells/reference.html

```html
<a 
  class="action-menu-item"
  text="$col.getLabel($row())"
  attr="href: $col.getUrl($row())"/>
```

5. Clear cache

```
$  php bin/magento cache:flush
$  php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: thank you for providing the solution. I will check and let you know.

Comment: Is it working for you ?

Comment: I didn't check but I did it in alternate way(added it in Customer Grid->Edit->Customer View->Personal Information) because I have added lot of fields. There, I added the href to uploaded files.

Comment: I use your tricks. Its working fine. Thank you!!