# How to show url link in magento grid column

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, url

I want to add url in magento grid.If i click on that link then it takes me to desire page.
Similar to that image[image]

I am making columns in grid like this.

```
<column name="product_name" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products\Product">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>

                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product Name</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

    </column>

    <column name="sku" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products\Product">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>

                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">SKU</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

Comment: Post your code you did till now with the issue you are facing.

Comment: If use UI Component, then Check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/156859/how-to-add-href-to-custom-attribute-in-customer-grid/157892#157892

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using UI component to build that grid then you need to replace your **product** column definition with something like this (for regular xml layout update):

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" as="score">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Product</argument>
        <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">product</argument>
        <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">string</argument>
        <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Column\Renderer\Product</argument>
        <argument name="header_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-product</argument>
        <argument name="column_css_class" xsi:type="string">col-product</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

And after then you need to create renderer class for that column

`Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Column\Renderer\Product`

```
<?php

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;

class Product extends AbstractRenderer {

    /**
     * Render link for product
     *
     * @param  \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {
        $value =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
        $url = $this->getUrl('');
        $output = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $value . '</a>';
        return $output;
    }
}
```

This works on Magento 2.1 and 2.1.2 (tested)

EDIT: I saw that your are using `ui_component` folder inside adminhtml and now you will need to modify your `Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products\Product` class and create `prepareDataSource()` method and modify dataSource to add links

Take a look at [Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\ViewAction](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/ViewAction.php) and see how view link on orders grid is implemented.

Hope this will help you to create your custom urls.

Comment: i have updated question and add ui code. Where did i add above block xml ?

Comment: See my updated answer and visit the link for ViewAction to get idea how to modify dataSource and display link with your column renderer

Comment: i had used same approach before but in column it shows [object Object]

Comment: this is for actionsColumn how can i add it in column ?

Comment: you have class for your column right? then modify prepareDataSource() method for it with the example above and add link for each item